# creating package error meteor

Tags: meteor, atmosphere

I have created a new meteor package using

```
meteor create --package name:app
```

I gave name as my meteor account(I logged in my system also)

then changed some code and when I try to publish package package using

```
meteor publish --create
```

from within meteor package dir

It is throwing error

```
Only administrators can create top-level packages without an account prefix.
(To confirm that you wish to create a top-level package with no account
prefix, please run this command again with the --top-level option.)

Did you mean to create name:app instead?
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Same error when using the `publish-release` command instead?

Comment: package.js what is the name of the package? You should make "username:name" I think you got it like "name" which isn't possible only meteor team can create those packages :)